# how can i process error in fetch api react?

Tags: reactjs

> I am sending api request using fetch in my Reactjs component. but
> after response it is not coming to then block. may be some error is
> coming in response. I want to redirect to error page if errors happen

```
fetch('endpoint')
.then(r => { 
> what if response is not ok 
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use catch function to deal with errors in fetch api

```
fetch('endpoint')
  .then(r => { 
      // deal with response flow
  })
  .catch(err => {
      console.error(err)
      //> deal with error flow
  })
```

Refer below link for more information
[https://www.tjvantoll.com/2015/09/13/fetch-and-errors/#:~:text=Per%20MDN%2C%20the%20fetch(),such%20a%20DNS%20lookup%20failure](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2015/09/13/fetch-and-errors/#:%7E:text=Per%20MDN%2C%20the%20fetch(),such%20a%20DNS%20lookup%20failure).

Answer (score 1):

Look into Promise catch blocks:

```
fetch('https://no-such-server.blabla') // rejects
  .then(response => response.json())
  .catch(err => alert(err)) // Here is where you handle the error
```

*Reference: https://javascript.info/promise-error-handling*